# Is there any pattern or practice to introduce debug/log code to an already existing algorithm in a non-intrusive way in .NET?

Tags: .net, algorithm, caching, logging, decorator

Let's pose that I have an already existing large algorithm that makes some calculations and returns a result:

```
public int JustSomeHeavyCalculations() {
    var storeSthing = PrivateFunction1("param");
    if (Somecondition) {
        var variable = member.DoSomething() + member2.DoSomething2()
    }

    CallSomePrivateFunction();
    return storeSthing * someRandNumber;
}
```

Now I have a new requirement that says that I have to log on a file and print on Console the value of "variable" and that the PrivateFunction1 is an expensive operation and should be cached in a way that calling it again with the same params immediately returns the cached value.

I could go easy on this, modify the function and add all those statements, but this not only would be for me a violation of the Open-Closed principle, but also I feel like it would break with the flow of the algorithm.

What's the best way to handle this kind of situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look to me to be the classic types of cross cutting concerns that Aspect-Oriented programming is intended to address.  Cross cutting concerns span layers and tiers in the code but ideally you want to implement in one place in a non-intrusive manner.  Aspect Oriented programming allows behaviour to be applied to classes from outside of the class heirachy either at compile or at run time.

[Microsoft Application Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee658105.aspx) guide has a good section on what cross cutting concerns are as well as some ideas on how to implement them.  A google for .NET Aspect Oriented Programming will find the various libraries that implement Aspects on .NET or start on the [aosd.net](http://www.aosd.net/) web site.